# Push changes for some files in different branch Github

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repository with many directories.
I am making changes to multiple of these directories.

I want to create a separate branch for each one of these directories and push my changes on each branch for the selected files only.
While being on master branch (confirmed with `git status`) and at the exact directory that I want to commit&push, I tried:

```
git add Files_for_branch01
git commit -m "files 01”
git checkout -b branch01 
git push -u origin branch01
```

but all changes were uploaded. I mean I got on branch01 changes of Files_for_branch02.

I'm completely confused. Any ideas?

Comment: What branch were you on before you started? Because that's the branch you committed the changes to, and then you made a copy of that branch called `branch01`. You also didn't show how you created `branch02`. Maybe you didn't switch or reset to before that commit when you created `branch02`? Also, run `git status` after the `git add` command to make sure you are only adding the files you want to that commit.

Comment: Worth pointing out: Git never pushes *files*. Git pushes only *commits*. Commits do *contain* files (so that's how you get files in Git), but the push works commit-by-commit, as it were. Branches are less important than you might think: they only serve to *find* commits; it's the commits that matter.

Comment: Besides this, Git never stores *changes*. Each commit has a full snapshot of every file (that the commit has, that is). To view *changes*, Git will pull two commits out of the repository and compare the two snapshots. All the files that are the same in the two commits are boring, and Git says nothing about those. For the files that are *different*, Git will figure out a way to change one to the other, and show you that.

Answer (score 0):

Command `git add` is used to add files that are not already being tracked, but in your case it sounds like the folders and their contents existed when you cloned.  In this case, `git commit` would still include changes made to any of these files.

If you only want the commit to include files from a certain path then add the path specification.  For example, replace `git commit -m "files 01”` with:

```
git commit -m "files 01” "path_to_files/*"
```

I would make sure to keep the `git add` as well just in case you added any new files.

More details on `git commit` options can be found here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit